# how to upgrade from laravel 5 to laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel

How can i up grade from Laravel 5.2 to Laravel 6 without changing my Laravel 5.2 directories.I have tried changing the composer.json file line to "laravel/framework": "6.*", from "laravel/framework": "5.2.*" but with no success

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/upgrade

Answer (score 1):

To be honest you should make update step by step.

First upgrade 5.2 to 5.3, then to 5.4 and so on...
Each version has little difference.

Take a look this page. You have manual how to do it.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade

Then read: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade

and so on...

That is why so important to make upgrading regularly.

Comment: Yeah i guess currently one or 2 commands don't do the upgrade like i thought.